# Use specific PHP file for specific directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create mod_rewrite rules that rewrite based on the first level directory name plus a failover to rewrite to a standard file in case none of the directory names are matched.

Example:

I have units.php, models.php and other.php. The other.php file should handle all non-assigned requests.

http://www.mydomain.com/units/4435
Should redirect to /units.php?id=4435

http://www.mydomain.com/models/594
Should redirect to /models.php?id=594

http://www.mydomain.com/anything
Should redirect to /other.php?id=anything

http://www.mydomain.com/anything/893
Should redirect to /other.php?id=anything/893

Let me know if this makes sense. I am unsure of how to structure the rules and conditions to achieve what I want.

This is what I have tried to sfar. It works for URLs starting with 'units' or 'models' but I get a 500 Error if I try any other URL:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(units)/(.+)$ /units.php?id=$2 [L,NC] 
RewriteRule ^(models)/(.+)$ /models.php?id=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /other.php?id=$2 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(units|models)/([0-9]+)/?$ /$1.php?id=$2  [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/(units|models)/[0-9]+/?$
RewriteRule ^/[^/]+/([0-9]+)/?$ /other.php?id=$1  [L,QSA]
```